# How can I use a parameter in an interface that is defined by the interface

Tags: c#

I try to define an interface like this:

```
public interface Something
{
   void f();
}
public interface SomethingElse
{
   void g(Something s);
}
```

This should say that g takes a parameter that adheres to the interface "Something". When I try to create classes the compiler will reject the SomethingElse class because it does not match the signature of the interface definition. But how should I define the interface?

```
class Something_class : Something
{
   public void f() { Console.WriteLine("Something.f"); }
}
class SomethingElse_class : SomethingElse
{
   public void g(Something_class s) { Console.WriteLine("SomethingElse.g"); }
}
```

Comment: just use void g(Something s) in SomethingElse_class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       class SomethingElse_class : SomethingElse
        {
            public void g(Something_class s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SomethingElse.g");
            }
            public void g(Something s) //overload g with the (Something s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something.g");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SomethingElse` interface says that any implementation needs to accept *any* type which implements `Something` - not just one specific example.

Either you need to change `SomethingElse_class` to:

```
class SomethingElse_class : SomethingElse
{
   public void g(Something s) { Console.WriteLine("SomethingElse.g"); }
}
```

... or make `SomethingElse` generic, e.g.

```
public interface SomethingElse<T> where T : Something
{
   void g(T s);
}
```

then `SomethingElse_class` would be:

```
class SomethingElse_class : SomethingElse<Something_class>
{
   public void g(Something_class s) { ... }
}
```